# No 401k available, max contribution for IRA and Roth

Tags: ira, roth-ira

I'm a higher income w2 contractor through a no-frills agency. No 401K. What is my max contribution that I can make to my personal IRA\Roth combined, and which should account type should I prefer.

For 2014 tax year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the 2014 tax year the max contribution is $0. You can no longer contribute to the IRA for 2014, the latest was April 15th 2015.

For the 2015 (current) tax year, the answer depends not only on your own situation, but also your spouses. You can see the limits [here](https://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/Plan-Participant,-Employee/Retirement-Topics-IRA-Contribution-Limits). Keep in mind that for the Traditional IRA, there are two limits: the $5500 overall contribution limit, and the limit on how much you can deduct.

Comment: Brain fart. I meant 2015 tax year.  The link was helpful.